# Controller Laravel?

Tags: css, array, laravel-5, controller

Como consigo estilizar um objeto em um `array` no `controller` Laravel?

```
Mapper::marker($marker['lat'], 
          $marker['lng'],['label'=> "<div>".$marker['label']."</div>"]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){

  Mapper::map(-22.886449, -43.118474,
      [   'marker'=>false,
          'zoom' => 10,
          'draggable' => true,
          'center' => true,
          'cluster' => false,
          'markers' => [
          'eventBeforeLoad' => 'addMapStyling(map);',
          'icon' =>'img/ida_22.png',
          'title' => '166001',
          'animation' => 'DROP'],
      ]);

      $markers = array(['lat' => -22.886449,'lng' => -43.118474,'label'=> 'Veículo 01'],
                       ['lat' => -22.885632,'lng' => -43.118143,'label'=> 'Veículo 02'],
                       ['lat' => -22.883990,'lng' => -43.119513,'label'=> 'Veículo 03'],
                       ['lat' => -22.885734,'lng' => -43.124988,'label'=> 'Veículo 04']);

      foreach ($markers as $marker) {
            //dd($marker['label']);
            Mapper::marker($marker['lat'], $marker['lng'],
                          ['label'=> $marker['label']]);

           Mapper::informationWindow($marker['lat'], $marker['lng'], $marker['label']);
      }

    return view('rastreamento.mapa.mapa');
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="#map-canvas-0">
    {!! Mapper::render() !!}
</div>
```

O nome do pacote e cornford googlmapper

Perciso que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você configura o estilo na própria View e no Controller só envia dados!? entendeu

Comment: Eu estou usando aquele pacote do cornford google mapper, que facilita aintegração com mapa da google, pórem toda a logica roda no controller, na view fica apenas uma variavel renderizada e no controller fica como o exemplo abaixo:
              foreach ($markers as $marker) {
                   Mapper::marker($marker['lat'], $marker['lng'],['label'=> $marker['label']]);          Mapper::informationWindow($marker['lat'], $marker['lng'], $marker['label']);
              }

Comment: Coloque o nome do pacote, coloque todo o código, coloque um exemplo de como fica e como você quer que fique estilo ... !!! é pouca informação.

Answer (score 1):

Lembre-se de não ferir os princípios do **padrão de arquitetur**a MVC.

Controller só coordena a comunicação entre Model e View. Ele não deve conhecer implementações e nem deve conter regras de negócio.

Exemplo:

Você poderia criar um método em seu model com toda a implementação do mapa, retornar como um array, chamar o método do model no controller, passá-lo para view e iterar esse array com o @foreach do blade.

Seu index no Controller ficaria assim:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('caminho.nome.da.view', ['mappeds' => Mapper::mappedItems()]);
}
```

Na view

```
@forelse($mappeds as $mapped)
{{ $mapped->value }}
@else
<p>Nenhum resultado encontrado</p>
@endforelse
```

Ou, implemente da maneira que desejar.

**Lembre-se:**

**Model** só ele conhece **implementações de regra de negócio, validação, verificação** e etc..

**View** só conhece a **entrada e saída de dados**.

**Controller** **coordena** o **Model** e a **View** invocando metódos, **sem conhecer** suas implementações.